# Black dot rendering a 360 Video

Tags: camera

I recently started rendering a 360 scene and when it is finished rendering it shows a black dot in the scene. There is no mesh making that black dot and it has never happened before. I attached a picture to further explain.[image]

Comment: What is your camera clipping set at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera clipping plane is cutting through your geometry. Under Camera settings > Lens > Clipping, set the Start value to a smaller value.